# How to instantiate a class in a Java .class using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am using `Visual Studio Code (version 1.32.3)` with `Java`. I have a .class file called 'RandomGenerator.class' which I want to instantiate from the main. The main.java and RandomGenerator.class are in the same directory.

My statement:

```
RandomGenerator rdgen = new RandomGenerator(1,1,1,1);
```

will have an error :`RandomGenerator could not be resolved to a type java(16777218)`

I tried to include import RandomGenerator; (I don't need but try to see if it is required) - I get an error `"RandomGenerator cannot be resolved java(268435846)"` at the import statement.

The specification of the constructor given is `RandomGenerator​(int seed, double lambda, double mu, double rho)`

Appreciate help to make it work in Visual Studio Code. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and use text formatting to separate code samples and highlight the error you get to make the question easier to understand?

Comment: The main.java and RandomGenerator.class are in the same directory. That is unusual, classes are usually loaded from a separate directory and the compiler won't look for class files in the source directory. Better to place the class file into a `lib/classes/` directory and add that to the classpath. It is also unusual to distribute classes as individual files. Normally, people give you a jar file. Or even better, get the source code for that file and put that next to your other Java files.

Comment: Also, probably that class will be declared to live in a specific package, so putting it in random places is probably not helping.

Comment: I have created a sub folder for lib/classes and added the classpath but the problem is still not resolved. I am only given the RandomGenerator.class and do not have any source code. The customer required me to use this class. I may have missed some setup in Visual Studio Code. Anyway thanks to all for suggesting.

Comment: maybe you could try to make the class to a `.jar`,then put it into `lib` folder,and add the path to `classpath`

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure RandomGenerator.class is on your path!
2. Import the class in the file that is using it!

If that does not work - is RandomGenerator visible or your class, i.e. public or package private and in the same package?